# Stream Closed FileInputStream

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have this problem
I try to download a file with this method, but when I try to download it throws this error.

```
    public void prepDownload(String noIM, String ejerc, String ubicFi, 
    Integer opc) throws Exception 
    {
    direArch = "";

    if (opc == 1) {
        direArch = ubicFi + ejerc + "\\" + noIM + "\\" + noIM + "-" + ejerc + ".pdf";
    }
    System.out.println(direArch);
    File file = new File(direArch);
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(file);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(file.getName()), file.getName()));

    } catch (IOException e) {


        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "

  the file can not be downloaded", ""));

    } finally{
        if (input!=null){
            input.close();
        }

    }
}


public void setDownload(DefaultStreamedContent download) {
    this.download = download;

}

public DefaultStreamedContent getDownload() throws Exception {

    return download;

}
```

Stack Trace

```
    java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:233)
    at org.primefaces.component.filedownload.
    FileDownloadActionListener.processAction
    (FileDownloadActionListener.java:90)
```

I have already tried verifying first the existence of the file without any results.

I would like to know mainly, if the cause is due to the position of input.close (). Is there another way to close?

Comment: A DefaultStreamedContent object can’t do anything with an InputStream that you immediately close.  Don’t close it;  let the DefaultStreamedContent object take care of that.

Comment: Yes you are closing your Stream in the finally {} block.  Don't do that let DefaultStreamedContent close it for you automatically.  Just hand it the InputStream.